# Bind9: limit query from subnet

Tags: dns, bind

I have a linux machine with a WiFi Hotspot assigning IP's in the 172.30.108.0/24 network.

I have bind 9 installed.
my named.conf only includes "include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";", everything else is disabled.

My named.conf.local has:

```
options {
        listen-on port 53 { 0.0.0.0; };
        listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
        directory       "/var/cache/bind";
        allow-query     { localhost; };
        recursion yes;
        querylog yes;
};



acl clients {
   172.30.108.0/24;
};

view "internal-view" {
  match-clients { internal; };
  allow-query { internal; };
  allow-query-cache { internal; };

  zone "limit.com." {
     type master;
     file "/etc/bind/db.limit.com";
  };

  # Mapping: Everything else to 127.0.0.1 
  zone "." {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.mapping";
  };

};

view "external-view" {
  match-clients { any; };
  allow-query { any; };
  allow-recursion { any; };
  allow-query-cache { any; };

  zone "wiincon.de." {
     type master;
     file "/etc/bind/db.limit.com";
  };

  include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
};
```

My db.limit.com:

```
; BIND reverse data file for broadcast zone
;
$TTL    180
@       IN      SOA     localhost. root.localhost. (
                              5         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      localhost.

@       IN      A       192.168.5.5
www     IN      A       192.168.5.5
```

and finally my db.mapping:

```
; BIND reverse data file for broadcast zone
;
$TTL    3600
@       IN      SOA     localhost. root.localhost. (
                              4         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      localhost.

*       IN      A       127.0.0.1
```

My problem is now: the clients in 172.30.108.0/24 can query anything BUT www.limit.com

Actually: Clients from 172.30.108.0/24 should be able to resolve limit.com and www.limit.com, everything else should respond with 127.0.0.1.

When doing a nslookup I get

Non-authoraive answer:
*** can't find limit.com: no answer

I'm sure I'm missing something very obvious here. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. The problem was that the "SYSTEM" itself had 8.8.8.8 as the name server, hence bypassing everything local.

Comment: Which gives you this morale of the story: prefer `dig` over `nslookup` and **always** specify which nameserver you query when troubleshooting, starting with the authoritative ones then the recursive ones, to understand better the reply you get.